# Why did my UPDATE statement not complete?

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking, blocking

Running SQL Server 2008; Mgmt Studio 2008. I am working with a MS SQL job that we have created for our MS CRM 4.0 implementation.  For anyone familiar with CRM, this job purges the aSyncOperationBase table nightly to save on DB size.  Here is the job code:

```
    Begin Transaction T1

Declare @p30Days as DateTime
Declare @p3Years as DateTime

Set @p30Days = DateAdd(d, -30, GetDate())
Set @p3Years = DateAdd(d, -1095, GetDate())

update AsyncOperationBase 
set deletionstatecode=2    
where deletionstatecode = 0 and 
statecode = 3 and 
completedon is not null and 
completedon < @p30Days   
and OperationType <> 10

update AsyncOperationBase 
set deletionstatecode=2    
where deletionstatecode = 0 and 
statecode = 3 and 
completedon is not null and 
completedon < @p3Years   
and OperationType = 10

delete from workflowlogbase    
where AsyncOperationid in (select AsyncOperationid from AsyncOperationBase where deletionstatecode=2)   

update DuplicateRecordBase 
set DeletionStateCode = 2    
where asyncoperationid in    
(select DuplicateRecordBase.asyncoperationid 
    from DuplicateRecordBase    
        left join asyncoperationbase on (DuplicateRecordBase.asyncoperationid=asyncoperationbase.asyncoperationid and    
        asyncoperationbase.deletionstatecode = 0) 
    where asyncoperationbase.asyncoperationid is null)    

update BulkDeleteOperationBase 
set DeletionStateCode = 2    
where asyncoperationid in    
(select BulkDeleteOperationBase.asyncoperationid 
    from BulkDeleteOperationBase    
        left join asyncoperationbase on (BulkDeleteOperationBase.asyncoperationid=asyncoperationbase.asyncoperationid and    
        asyncoperationbase.deletionstatecode = 0) 
    where asyncoperationbase.asyncoperationid is null)    

delete from asyncoperationbase 
where deletionstatecode = 2 and 
completedon < @p30Days  

commit transaction T1
```

The problem that I recently noticed is that this job, which starts at 4am, runs for at least 4 hours and does not complete.  As I tried run the first update statement against 1 record, the SQL process did not complete and became the lead blocker in the process chain.  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this behavior?  I have looked at the Activity Monitor and there are no other processes which are causing major blockages.

Comment: What are the indexes you have on the tables in this job?

Comment: I have non-clustered indexes on the columns in the first update query that I tried to update 1 row from.  I re-built all of the indexes but no change in execution.

Comment: What's the wait information for the query? What's the execution plan look like?

Comment: @Gryphoenix Try to see if there are connections blocking your current transaction. Maybe you have already a long running transaction, or there is a transaction left open. You can find [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/sql-server-backup-process-tuning/3129#3129) some help about finding information regarding blocking/blocked processes.

Comment: How many rows are deleted? Do you shrink your databases at all?

Comment: The clustered index update, for the primary key, takes up a majority of the query cost at 65%.  The other heavy hitters are 2 Table Spool (Eager Spool) at 24%

Comment: The rows are not deleted by this update statement.  Only one field for each row is updated.

Comment: most of the times when your WHERE clause is not fetching needed rows then the update does not works

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if these statements are blocking each other.  Since they are in the same transaction.  Do they somehow lock conflicting rows?

```
update AsyncOperationBase 
set deletionstatecode=2    
where deletionstatecode = 0 and 
statecode = 3 and 
completedon is not null and 
completedon < @p30Days   
and OperationType <> 10

update AsyncOperationBase 
set deletionstatecode=2    
where deletionstatecode = 0 and 
statecode = 3 and 
completedon is not null and 
completedon < @p3Years   
and OperationType = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try running a trace with profiler and and checking for blocking [deadlocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx). 
Might need to enable some trace flags to see whats really going on.